# Does the latest picture of EHT mean the end to the no hair theorem?

Tags: black-holes, magnetic-fields, event-horizon, accretion-disk

I couldn't help but noticing what looks like "hair" in the [latest image from EHT](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2021/mar/24/mysterious-swirling-light-provides-new-clue-to-black-holes).
Does this mean the end of the [no hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem)?
Pun intended but also a serious question.

Comment: Why would this mean the end?

Comment: "Suppose two black holes have the same masses, electrical charges, and angular momenta, but the first black hole was made by collapsing ordinary matter whereas the second was made out of antimatter; nevertheless, then the conjecture states they will be completely indistinguishable to an observer outside the event horizon. " Why would all black holes of the same charge, mass and AM look exactly like this?

Comment: These images show light coming from matter around the black hole. This falls outside the scope of the no-hair conjecture, the conjecture only talks about properties of the black hole itself. These magnetic fields don't have to be those of the black hole.

Comment: @NDeWolf That is the question indeed.

Comment: Their video shows that the resolution of the entire BH image is about 3x3 pixels or so processed by a creative imaging algorithm. The new "polarized" image is made up as a composite of several low resolution frames. So the magnetic field "hairs" shown are only as "real" as the magnetic field lines drawn on pictures of magnets for children. The resolution of these hairs exceeds the actual resolution of the telescope by two orders of magnitude, so they are not real, but a computer aided wishful thinking at best: https://eventhorizontelescope.org/files/eht/files/eht_pol_anim_202103.mp4